# How to fix "Exactly one of TransitionDate and TransitionInDays must be specified" in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

When I'm going to create an S3 bucket by the Cloudformation stack it's sending me this error message: 'Exactly one of TransitionDate and TransitionInDays must be specified'.
The transition in days is specified as per the code below:

```
Resources:
  S3CreateBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
          BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}"

          BucketEncryption:
            ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
              - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                  SSEAlgorithm: AES256
          LoggingConfiguration:
            DestinationBucketName: xxxx
            LogFilePrefix: !Sub "{AWS::StackName}"/                      
          LifecycleConfiguration:
            Rules:
              - Id: Multipartupload
                Status: 'Enabled'
                AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload:
                  DaysAfterInitiation: 7 
                ExpirationInDays: 180                     
              -  Id: Glacier
                 Status: 'Enabled'
                 Transitions:                  
                  - StorageClass: GLACIER
                  - TransitionInDays: 90            
          Tags:
            -
             Key: Name
             Value: public
          VersioningConfiguration:
            Status: Enabled
          WebsiteConfiguration:
            ErrorDocument: error.html
            IndexDocument: index.html
```

What I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your format for the 'Transitions' section is incorrect. I believe this would work:

```
  S3CreateBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
          BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}"

          BucketEncryption:
            ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
              - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                  SSEAlgorithm: AES256
          LoggingConfiguration:
            DestinationBucketName: xxxx
            LogFilePrefix: !Sub "{AWS::StackName}"/                      
          LifecycleConfiguration:
            Rules:
              - Id: Multipartupload
                Status: 'Enabled'
                AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload:
                  DaysAfterInitiation: 7 
                ExpirationInDays: 180                     
              -  Id: Glacier
                 Status: 'Enabled'
                 Transition:                  
                   StorageClass: GLACIER
                   TransitionInDays: 90            
          Tags:
            -
             Key: Name
             Value: public
          VersioningConfiguration:
            Status: Enabled
          WebsiteConfiguration:
            ErrorDocument: error.html
            IndexDocument: index.html
```

Note I've changed Transitions to Transition and removed the 2 separate lists
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule-transition.html

If you wanted to use Transitions as you were planning on adding more than one transition, then you would do something like below:

```
    Transitions:
      - StorageClass: String
        TransitionDate: Timestamp
        TransitionInDays: Integer
      - StorageClass: String
        TransitionDate: Timestamp
        TransitionInDays: Integer
```